# Android ListView - how to react to item clicks?

Tags: android, listview

Let's say that I have a `ListView` with some items. I want to make it so when the user clicks on an item, the app pops up a `Toast` containing the name of the item. For example, when the user clicks "Apple", they are presented with the toast: "You ate Apple." How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set Item Click Listener on List View i.e.

```
listvw=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewid);

listvw.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {

            Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, "Text message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Same here. How to get the name of the pressed item?

Comment: You have a view of your listview item. just find the text of view i.e. ' TextView text= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_viewId); '
 'Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, text.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();'

Comment: OK thanks. I used `TextView text = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(arg1.getId()); Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text.getText(), Toast.LENGTH.SHORT).show();`

Answer (score 1):

Standard way it to use [`.setOnItemClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29).

Comment: But how to get the name of the pressed item?

Answer (score 0):

use like that

ActivityListView .java

```
package com.sunil;  

    import android.app.ListActivity; 
    import android.os.Bundle; 
    import android.view.View; 
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; 
    import android.widget.ListView; 
    import android.widget.Toast; 

    public class ActivityListView extends ListActivity {

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
     // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity 
     String[] namesArray = new String[] { "Linux", "Windows7", "Eclipse", 
        "Suse", "Ubuntu", "Solaris", "Android", "iPhone" }; 

     /* Create an ArrayAdapter, that will actually make the Strings above
      appear in the ListView */ 

     this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, namesArray)); 
     } 
      @Override 
      protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v,  
      int position, long id) { 
     super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id); 

     // Get the item that was clicked 

     Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position); 
     String keyword = o.toString(); 
     Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + keyword,  
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     } 
    }
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

    <LinearLayout 

     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 

     android:orientation="vertical" 

     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 

     android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

     <TextView 

      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 

      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

      android:text="@string/hello" /> 

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I get a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`. Maybe let's extend the standard `Activity` class, not `ListActivity`?

Comment: same code working in my device. Do not extends Activity and also setcontentview also . It will work fine check again

Answer (score 0):

Try this code
         listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listid);

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,long arg3) {

       // to set your list item or name  

        //here list is your list that you set in your adapter       
          list.get(pos);

    }
});
```